# What does `julia>` seen in code bracket examples in Julia language mean?

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia lang, and am seeing a lot of `julia>` in code examples in numerous documentation.

At first, I thought it was just a REPL code example, but I see them in code examples that look like scripts, so I'm confused.

example from [MJLFlux.jl repository](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/MLJFlux.jl):

```
using MLJ
import RDatasets
iris = RDatasets.dataset("datasets", "iris");
y, X = unpack(iris, ==(:Species), colname -> true, rng=123);
@load NeuralNetworkClassifier

julia> clf = NeuralNetworkClassifier()
NeuralNetworkClassifier(
    builder = Short(
            n_hidden = 0,
            dropout = 0.5,
            σ = NNlib.σ),
    finaliser = NNlib.softmax,
    optimiser = ADAM(0.001, (0.9, 0.999), IdDict{Any,Any}()),
    loss = Flux.crossentropy,
    epochs = 10,
    batch_size = 1,
    lambda = 0.0,
    alpha = 0.0,
    optimiser_changes_trigger_retraining = false) @ 1…60
```

Comment: I think it just means that they copied and pasted the code from a repl. Julia is smart enough to ignore `julia>` at the start of a line so you can copy paste.

Comment: Hmm I see. But why aren't there `julia>` at the beginning of the codes above as well? What context was the original code run in?

Comment: that's a great question. I have no idea why that would be the case.

Comment: quite confusing. . . thanks though!

Comment: My guess is that they wanted to show some outputs for specific lines in these minimal examples. So the lines for which they did not want output are shown condensed like in a script, while those lines with the `julia>` prompt are separated and show output from the REPL.

Comment: If that were the case, I would just use `print`. But I guess that's a newbie opinion. . .

Comment: It could be that some of the code is copied from a file, and some of it from the REPL. I, too, tend to be a bit inconsistent with when I include the `julia>` prompt and when I remove it.

Comment: I think that a good practice is to separate code blocks which are copied from the REPL, from those that aren't. The ability to copy-paste to the REPL is magic, but it only works if the entire segment copied is like that --- if you paste the block above, you will probably get "ERROR: error in method definition: function Base.> must be explicitly imported to be extended" as `julia> clf = NeuralNetworkClassifier()` is read as function definition `>(julia, clf) = ...`.

Comment: @mcabbott yes, that was the initial error I got that compelled me to ask this question. It would be nice to have distinctions and consistencies as you suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`julia>` is just the REPL prompt as you said.

One reason to include it in examples is so that the output of the command is shown immediately below the command itself. I think that is the reason for the inconsistency in your example code. The author probably omitted the prompt and output on the first few lines for brevity, but did want to show output from the final line.

Another reason may be to distinguish code which the author has stored in a file from code which is being run on the fly in the REPL. Code which sets up a problem environment is likely run once from the file, whereas code that calls the established functions may be tweaked and executed multiple times from the REPL.

There are no strict rules about this, and you may largely ignore it except to note that the text beneath the prompt is probably output rather than executed code. (Note that it is possible to have multiple input and output lines for one REPL prompt though.)

```
julia> for i in 1:5
           println(i)
       end
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Oh, so I guess it was rather intentionally mixed? I guess I just have to get used to it then. It's nice to have confirmation thought. Thank you.